# Наибольший элемент должен стоять первым, наименьший последним в новой копии массива

Tags: python, массивы

Задан одномерный массив А(1), А(2), … А(10), содержащий 10
элементов. Найти наибольшее и наименьшее значения элементов массива.
Изменить порядок следования элементов – наибольший элемент должен
стоять первым, наименьший последним в новой копии массива.

Наибольшее и наименьшее нашел, а вот как изменить порядок следования не понимаю, помогите, пожалуйста.

Нужно на Питоне.

Comment: При нахождении минимума и максимума следует запомнить также соответствующие индексы, и затем обменять элементы по найденным индексам.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот твой код:

```
# создаем массив
A = [5, 10, 2, 8, 1, 7, 9, 3, 6, 4]

# находим наибольшее и наименьшее значения
max_value = max(A)
min_value = min(A)

# выводим результат
print("Наибольшее значение: ", max_value)
print("Наименьшее значение: ", min_value)

# создаем новую копию массива с измененным порядком элементов
A.remove(min_value)
A.remove(max_value)
newA = [min_value] + A + [max_value]

# выводим новый массив
print(f"Новый массив: {newA}")
```

если правильно понял, то тебе не нужно сортировать весь массив в обратном порядке, а просто поменять значения местами. Если же тебе нужно сделать именно обратную сортировку, то:

```
sorted(A)[::-1]
```

Вместо создания нового массива.